# JSON (de)serializing for nested classes

Tags: python, json

`X` is a simple class with a 3 fields:

```
class X():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

JSON encoder/decoder for `X`:

```
class XEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):
        return super(XEncoder, self).encode({
            'a': obj.a,
            'b': obj.b,
            'c': obj.c
        })

class XDecoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    def decode(self, json_string):
        obj = super(XDecoder, self).decode(json_string)
        return X(obj['a'], obj['b'], obj['c'])
```

`Y` class which have `X` as a a value of a dict inside a field:

```
class Y():
    def __init__(self):
        self.m = {}

    def add(self, a, x):
        self.m[a] = x
```

How will JSON encoder/decoder for `Y` look?

Comment: I'd bet dollars to donuts a sane JSON library can encode a dict directly.

Comment: and how much for decoding?

Comment: You're **already** getting dicts back from the decoder. (You might have to map them and decode the values with something like `self.m = {k: XDecoder().decode(v) for k, v in super().decode(json_string)}['m'].items()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class YEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):
        return json.dumps({ 'm': json.dumps({ k: json.dumps(v, cls=XEncoder) for k, v in obj.m.items()})})

class YDecoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    def decode(self, json_string):
        y.m = {k: json.loads(v, cls=XDecoder) for k, v in json.loads(json.loads(json_string)['m']).items()}
        return y
```